# How to write dynamic attributes

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave

I need to write a dynamic Attribute name instead of hardcode of Name attribute in dataweave 2.0 mulesoft 4 in anypointstudio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<iGoApplicationData>
 <UserData>    
 <Data Name="UpdateUserProfile">True</Data>   
 <Data Name="Action">??</Data>
</iGoApplicationData>
```

Comment: Can you please fix your post. And also use the body of the post to clarify you question. Maybe an example of what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

So in order to generate an XML like yours the DW structure will look like

```
{
  iGoApplicationData: {
    UserData: {
      Data @(Name: payload.foo): "True",
      Data @((var.attributeName): "Action"): "??"
    }
  }
}
```

So in this example I show how to specify a value in the attribute or a dynamic attribute name. For the dynamic attribute value just type the expression on the value side of the attribute (the part that goes after the :) 
For dynamic attribute name you need to wrap the expression between parenthesis. When the name is wrapped between parenthesis it is considered dynamic. This applies to object keys and attributes names